# How to send your current location

Tags: ios, swift

I read through the documentation but couldn't find the reference. How do you use iOS to send the users location through a message? Such as in the screenshot below?

In iOS 8 there's the option to "Send My Current Location" in the Details Section of Messages, but I couldnt find a reference in the docs.

[image]

Comment: I believe that is a function of the iMessage application, not the MFMessageComposeViewController class.  You would need to create the location link as an attachment in your app